How to ignore SolverError in cvxpy?
I have an optimization problem with random inputs. When I solve the problem using cvxpy with cvxpy.MOSEK, I got on some random inputs the optimal solution and on some other inputs the SolverError error which stops the execution of the code. I want to continue the execution and simply ignore those random instances where cvxpy gives me SolverError.
Is there a way to do it?

It is an ordinary Python exception so you can just catch it in a try-except clause.
